# How to fit data logarithmic in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm

I've been trying to fit some data I have gained from some simulations. From the curve, I guess a logarithmic fit would be ideal. However, the curve comes looking out quite funky. I've also tried higher order polynomials and np.polyfit, but I couldn't get either to work. 
Any help would be appreciated!

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


xdata=[9.24104360013e-06, 4.72619458107e-06, 4.03957328857e-06, 9.78301182748e-06, 1.36994566431e-05, 1.16294573409e-05, 7.70899546232e-06, 2.72587766232e-06, 2.19089955631e-06, 5.34851640035e-06, 7.84434545123e-06, 7.6524185787e-06, 1.00592536363e-05, 6.08711035578e-07, 4.08259572135e-07, 5.74424798328e-07, 6.20036326494e-07, 4.34755225756e-06, 4.72832211908e-06, 1.25156011417e-06, 1.44996714816e-05, 3.79992166335e-06, 4.45935911838e-06, 6.6307841155e-06, 2.38540191336e-06, 9.4649801666e-07, 9.11518608157e-06, 3.1944675219e-06, 5.32674287313e-06, 1.48463901861e-05, 3.41127723277e-06, 3.40027150288e-06, 3.33064781566e-06, 2.12828505238e-06, 7.22565690506e-06, 7.86527964811e-06, 2.25791582571e-06, 1.94875869207e-05, 1.54712884424e-05, 5.82300791075e-06, 9.5783833758e-06, 1.89519143607e-05, 1.03731970283e-05, 2.53090894753e-05, 9.26047056658e-06, 1.05428610146e-05, 2.89162870493e-05, 4.78624726782e-05, 1.00005855557e-05, 6.88617910928e-05]

ydata=[0.00281616449359, 0.00257023004939, 0.00250030932407, 0.00284317789756, 0.00300158447316, 0.00291690879783, 0.00274898865728, 0.0023625485679, 0.0023018015629, 0.00259860025555, 0.00269155777824, 0.00265941197135, 0.0028073724168, 0.00192920496041, 0.00182900945464, 0.00191452746379, 0.00193227563253, 0.00253266811688, 0.00255961306471, 0.00212426145702, 0.00285906942634, 0.00247877245272, 0.0025348504727, 0.00269881922057, 0.00232270371493, 0.00204672286703, 0.00281306442303, 0.00241938445736, 0.00261083321385, 0.00287440363274, 0.00244324770882, 0.00244364989768, 0.00244593671433, 0.00228714406931, 0.00263301289418, 0.00269385915315, 0.0022968948347, 0.00313898537645, 0.00305650121575, 0.00265291893623, 0.00278748794063, 0.00312801724905, 0.00289450806538, 0.00313176225397, 0.00284010926578, 0.0028957865422, 0.00335438183977, 0.00360421739757, 0.00270734995952, 0.00377301191882]


plt.plot(xdata,ydata,'o')

x = np.array(xdata, dtype=float) #transform your data in a numpy array of floats 
y = np.array(ydata, dtype=float) #so the curve_fit can work

#def func(x,a,b,c):
#    return a*x**2+ b*x +c

def func(x,a,b):
    return a*np.log(x)+ b


popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy.curve\_fit() returns multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516862/scipy-curve-fit-returns-multiple-lines)

Comment: If the data is logarithmic, you can compute the exponential and try a linear/polynomial fit.

Comment: You just need to sort your data while plotting the line. Use `plt.plot(sorted(x), func(sorted(x), *popt), label="Fitted Curve"); plt.legend()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort `x` before plotting

```
x_sorted = np.sort(x)
plt.plot(x_sorted, func(x_sorted, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can also just use `plt.plot(sorted(x), func(sorted(x), *popt), label="Fitted Curve")`

Comment: @Sheldore `sorted` is a python standard function, and thus is one order of magntitude slower than `np.sort` (at least on my machine). In addition, it returns a list, which you'd need to convert back to an `ndarray` again, if you process it further (does not matter just for plotting). Finally, you are calling the sorting algorithm twice, which is less efficient (does not matter in this case, either). Generally, when working with `ndarray`s, one should try to stick to pure `numpy` functions as much as possible.

Comment: Right, at least for such small list doesn’t make a difference though