# Polynomial Regression Curves

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, curve-fitting, polynomials

I'm trying to create a regression curve for my data, with 2 degrees. When I create my graph, I get a funny zigzag thing:
[image]
but I want to model my data as an actual curve, which would look like the connected version of the scatter plot.
[image]
Any advice/better ways of doing this?

```
degree = 2
p = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(data['input'],y, degree))
plt.plot(data['input'], p(data['input']), c='r',linestyle='-')
plt.scatter(data['input'], p(data['input']), c='b')
```

Here, data['input'] is a column vector with the same dimensions as y.

Edit: I have also tried it like this:

```
X, y = np.array(data['input']).reshape(-1,1), np.array(data['output'])
lin_reg=LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
lin_reg.fit(X,y)

poly_reg=PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_poly=poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
poly_reg.fit(X_poly,y)
lin_reg2=LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
lin_reg2.fit(X_poly,y)

X_grid=np.arange(min(X),max(X),0.1)
X_grid=X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid),1))
plt.scatter(X,y,color='red')
plt.plot(X,lin_reg2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X)),color='blue')
plt.show()
```

Which gives me this graph here.
[image]
The scatter is my data and the blue zigzag is what is SUPPOSED to be a quadratic curve modelling the data. Help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scipy.curve\_fit() returns multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516862/scipy-curve-fit-returns-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 0):

In your plot you just plot from point to point with straight lines (where your y value is the approximated y from your polyfit function).

I would skip the polyfit function (because you have all y values you are interested in) and just interpolate the `data['input']` and `y` with BSplines function `make_interp_spline` from `scipy` and plot the new y values with your interested range of x.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as interp
```

## plots just from point to point (zigzag)

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([75, 0, 25, 100])
plt.plot(x, y)
```

## interpolates the points

```
x_new = np.linspace(1, 4, 300)
a_BSpline = interp.make_interp_spline(x, y)
y_new = a_BSpline(x_new)
plt.plot(x_new, y_new)
```

Try this and then adjust with your data! :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much, but this doesn't seem to work. I am trying to create a regression curve with a polynomial basis function of order 2. The BSpline function just ives me a value error: "Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.". I'm wondering if there's a way to do this using sklearn, but I couldn't figure it out myself..

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

#improve degree = 3
p_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 3)
X_poly = p_reg.fit_transform(X)

#again create new linear regression obj
reg2 = LinearRegression()
reg2.fit(X_poly,y)
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'b')
plt.xlabel('Level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.title("Truth or Bluff")

# predicted values
plt.plot(X, reg2.predict(X_poly), color='r')
plt.show()
```

[With Degree 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q5r3.png)

[With Degree 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGlDM.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image: ![enter image description here]

Because you don't show us your data I SUPPOSE that your independent variable is not monotone.

My code below

1. it computes two data vectors where *y = y(x)* but *x* is not monotone
2. it computes a polynomial of 2nd degree fitting the data
3. it plots, in the left part of the figure above, the scatter plot of *x vs y* and a line plot of *x vs y=p(x)* where *y* is computed from the best fit polynomial
4. it sorts *x → xs*
5. in the right part of the figure above, it plots again the same scatter plot and the line plot of *xs vs y=p(xs)*.

.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

# x is not monotonic
x = np.random.random(60)
# y is quadratic with a quartic "error"
y = 0.3+1.2*x-1.4*(x-0.5)**2 - x**4/3
# find the 2nd degree poly1d object that best fits data
p = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 2))

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,4),layout='constrained')
s=6 ; lw=0.75
# what you did?
ax0.scatter(x, y, c='k', s=s)
ax0.plot(x, p(x), lw=lw)
# what you want?
xs = np.sort(x)
ax1.scatter(x, y, c='k', s=s)
ax1.plot(xs, p(xs), lw=lw)
#
plt.show()
```