# Plot line graph for tested and predicted values in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, sklearn-pandas

I have produced an OLS regression model where I have trained and tested the data:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.20)
```

I have then created the variable y_preds as follows:

```
X_test = sm.add_constant(X_test)
y_preds = results.predict(X_test)
```

I am now trying to plot test and predicted data on a line graph to see how well the model fits however my method is not working:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_preds})

df.plot(kind='line',figsize=(18,8))
plt.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='green')
plt.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
plt.show()
```

What happens is that the line graph shows two lines all over the place instead of two overlapping lines that go from left to right.

This is the link to the current output
[image: This is the link to the current output]

This is the link to the ideal output
[image: This is the link to the ideal output]

Comment: Define "all over the place" (an image would be good). Are your x-data sorted? If not, you have to do this before plotting.

Comment: can you show an example of what your data looks like and how your plot looks. your code works for me

Comment: Most likely unsorted x-values, see [for instance here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50516862/8881141). Where are the axes labels on the upper image?

Comment: What is `sm.add_constant` doing to the `X_test` variable?

Comment: Could it be a quirk of `df.plot`? Does using matplotlib directly fix this? e.g. `plt.plot(range(len(y_test)), y_test)` and `plt.plot(range(len(y_pred)), y_pred)`

Comment: @AndyS. Is date in your index? I don't see it mentioned anywhere, but I don't know sklearn. Maybe `df.sort_index(inplace=True)` will do?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes your solution did the trick. Using matplotlib directly fixed it. Thank you