# Scipy curve_fit not working with different data

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm trying to generate a function importing data from csv. I have identified that it seems to be because of the data I'm using. But I'm very new to Python etc. so I have no idea what is so different about them that I don't get the output I'm looking for.

[Obviously it should be a continuous line not this zig zag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVGH4.png)

Data that doesn't work:

| Leistung | Kosten |
| --- | --- |
| 10.4 | 754.7115385 |
| 13 | 691.4615385 |
| 17.4 | 547.0689655 |
| 5.8 | 1244.655172 |
| 7.5 | 1034.533333 |
| 42.3 | 368.534279 |
| 22 | 721.7727273 |
| 28 | 644.6071429 |

Data that works fine:

| Leistung | Kosten |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 18 |
| 50 | 12 |
| 100 | 1 |
| 150 | 9 |
| 200 | 9 |
| 250 | 8 |
| 300 | 6 |
| 500 | 6 |

The code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')
qin = x['Leistung']
inv = x['Kosten']

def cost(qin, c0, c1):
    return c0*np.power(qin, c1)

c = curve_fit(cost, qin, inv)

c0_fit = c[0][0]
c1_fit = c[0][1]

# Plot fitted diagram
fit = []
for i in qin:
    fit.append(cost(i, c0_fit, c1_fit))

plt.plot(qin, fit)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Leistung')
plt.ylabel('Kosten')
plt.grid
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update your question so that your data is included in the post itself. Also I am definitely missing some imports/function declarations to run your code. Please make it a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask would probably be an interesting read too. These edits will help others to help you (:.

Comment: It is not a fitting problem. [Your x-data are not sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516979/8881141).