# How to get rid of weird stray lines in scatterplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot, data-fitting

I'm dealing with the well-known `Gapminder` data file (here:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tklimonova/gapminder-datacamp-2007?select=gapminder_full.csv)

**df.head()**:

```
        country     year    population  continent   life_exp         gdp_cap
0   Afghanistan     2007      31889923       Asia     43.828      974.580338
1   Albania         2007       3600523     Europe     76.423     5937.029526
2   Algeria         2007      33333216     Africa     72.301     6223.367465
3   Angola          2007      12420476     Africa     42.731     4797.231267
4   Argentina       2007      40301927   Americas     75.320    12779.379640
```

I tried a `scatter plot` but get confused by the many lines appearing on the plot:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn')

x = np.array(df['gdp_cap'])
y = np.array(df['life_exp'])

plt.scatter(x, y, marker = 'o', alpha = 1)

coeff = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)

plt.plot(x, coeff[0]*(x**2) + coeff[1]*x + coeff[2])

plt.show()
```

[image]

What I am doing wrong ???

Comment: Your x-values are not sorted. See, for instance, here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50516862/8881141

Comment: The lines are created with `plt.plot` as it defaults to a line plot. Use argument of `ls='', marker='.'` for `plt.plot` or switch it into `plt.scatter`.

Comment: `plot.scatter`does the work. Thanks `np8`

Answer (score 0):

Your second plot overdraws the first plot. Do add another `plt.show()` to prevent overdrawing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('seaborn')

x = np.array(df['gdp_cap'])
y = np.array(df['life_exp'])

plt.scatter(x, y, marker = 'o', alpha = 1)
plt.show()

coeff = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
plt.plot(x, coeff[0]*(x**2) + coeff[1]*x + coeff[2])

plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image: output]