# Issue when plotting polynomial regression curve

Tags: python, plot, regression, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

I have run linear and polynomial regression but when I'm plotting the results for the polynomial regression it is not showing a curve for a single line but multiple lines. It could be a very simple code issue but I cannot resolve it.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

pre_process = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 5)

poly_model = LinearRegression()
poly_model.fit(data_train_x,train_y)

print(poly_model.coef_)
print(poly_model.intercept_)

# Prediction on validation dataset
data_valid_x = pre_process.fit_transform(valid_x)
poly_pred = poly_model.predict(data_valid_x)

plt.scatter(valid_x, valid_y, facecolor='None', edgecolor='k', alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(valid_x, poly_pred)
plt.show()
```

This is the result of the polynomial regression fit:
[image]

Comment: Your x-data are not sorted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516979/8881141

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realized that. It is showing the correct plot now.